# PHP - Creating 'DYNAMIC' Directories For HTML5 <AUDIO>

Tags: php, html, echo, html5-audio, readdir

So... I'm a mega noob when it comes to PHP, trying my best to learn but **ITS NOT GOOD ENOUGH.**
Anyways, what I am attempting to do is set up 2 different 'dynamic' directories within a  PHP echo structured to fit an HTML5 audio tag.
- 1st directory for *.mp3
- 2nd directory for *.ogg
I'm trying to set it up so that I can just dump the corresponding file formats into their respective folders and voila! Auto generated HTML5 audio playback...
Should be easy enough, no? 100% sure I'm doing this the worst way possible.
Here's the code....

```
    <?PHP
        $handleAudioMp3 = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/audio/mp3/');
        $handleAudioOgg = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/audio/ogg/');
        while($fileMp3 = readdir($handleAudioMp3) & $fileOgg = readdir($handleAudioOgg)){
            if($fileMp3 !== '.' && $fileMp3 !== '..' && $fileOgg !== '.' && $fileOgg !== '..'){
                echo '<div>
                        <audio controls="controls" preload="none">
                            <source src="audio/mp3/'.$fileMp3.'"/>
                            <source src="audio/ogg/'.$fileOgg.'"/>
                        </audio>
                    </div>'     ;}}
                    closedir($handleAudioMp3);
                    closedir($handleAudioOgg);
    ?>
```

Revised & working thanks to **ThiefMaster**

```
<?PHP
        $handleAudioMp3 = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/audio/mp3/');
        $handleAudioOgg = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/audio/ogg/');
        while(($fileMp3 = readdir($handleAudioMp3)) & ($fileOgg = readdir($handleAudioOgg))){
            if($fileMp3 !== '.' && $fileMp3 !== '..' && $fileOgg !== '.' && $fileOgg !== '..'){
                echo '<div>
                        <audio controls="controls" preload="none">
                            <source src="audio/mp3/'.$fileMp3.'" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                            <source src="audio/ogg/'.$fileOgg.'" type="audio/ogg"/>
                        </audio>
                    </div>'     ;}}
                    closedir($handleAudioMp3);
                    closedir($handleAudioOgg);
    ?>
```

the difference is...

```
while(($fileMp3 = readdir($handleAudioMp3)) & ($fileOgg = readdir($handleAudioOgg))){
```

Comment: Try adding some parentheses. `&` is not meant to be used in this way so it doesn't have the same priorities as `&&`. That might not fix your code though since `readdir()` results are not sorted

Comment: ThiefMaster,
Thanks for the quick reply!
Not sure if I exactly understand... do you mean within...
while($fileMp3 = readdir($handleAudioMp3) & $fileOgg = readdir($handleAudioOgg)){
changing & to &&???
I know I'm going about this the wrong way but I'm sure sure what to do.

Comment: `while((a = b) & (c = d))` instead of `while(a = b & c = d)`

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU,THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU... THANK YOU @ThiefMaster!!! flew right over my head!
[answer] while((a = b) & (c = d)) instead of while(a = b & c = d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ThiefMaster** pointed out that I had forgotten some parentheses within...

```
while($fileMp3 = readdir($handleAudioMp3) & $fileOgg = readdir($handleAudioOgg)){
```

So it should be...

```
while(($fileMp3 = readdir($handleAudioMp3)) & ($fileOgg = readdir($handleAudioOgg))){
```

Thanks Again Everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat, here are two:

1. Let the user decide (e.g. via a select) which format he wants, then use only this format
2. display not 2 sources for 1 audio tag, but  2 audio tags, labelling
   them "play ogg" and "play mp3§

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Eugen Rieck!
Gonna do some think'n about it but from my understanding having 2 different tags would render 1 set not functional/dead in either Firefox or Webkit... No?

Comment: Letting the user choose is not really acceptable for `<audio>` tags. Some browsers support mp3, some don't, some support ogg, some don't. But having both available makes it work in all browsers and the browser will then choose a working `<source>`

Comment: While this is the theory, my experience is quite different: Multiple source definitions have proved problematic for an app intended to run on "all" browsers on "all" platforms.

Comment: My experiences differ... think it might have something to do with varying build versions?

Comment: I set up two tags...

<audio controls="controls">
<source src="file.mp3" />
</audio>

and...

<audio controls="controls">
<source src="file.ogg" />
</audio>

file.ogg works in firefox but not webkit...
file.mp3 works in webkit but not firefox...

Thus there are two players present but only one is functional...
by specifying dirrent <sources> within the <audio> tag the browser can choose which one works best, avoiding a useless player on the screen.